# How to create a seperate thread for in app billing

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am following the android [in app billing tutorial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) where it states:

> Warning: Don't call the getSkuDetails method on the main thread. Calling this method triggers a network request that could block your main thread. Instead, create a separate thread and call the getSkuDetails method from inside of that thread.

for the following code:

```
 IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                                   IBinder service) {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        Intent serviceIntent =
                new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        getActivity().bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        skuList.add("iap_one");
        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
        try {
            Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,
                    getActivity().getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response == 0) {
                ArrayList<String> responseList
                        = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                        String sku = object.getString("productId");
                        String price = object.getString("price");
                        Log.d("Test Price", price);
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected Remote exception", e);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` is the standard way to do things on a background thread in android.  Plenty of info on how to do that out there on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class that implements runnable and insert variables that you need  through constructor or use asynctask class

```
class ImplementsRunnable implements Runnable {
  private myvar;

  public ImplementsRunnable(String myvar){
    this.myvar=myvar;
  } 

  public void run() {
     System.out.println("ImplementsRunnable : myvar: " + myvar);
  }
```

}